# Reading a text file with Numpy/Pandas in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I have an unlabeled dataset which contains 101 columns i.e. no column have any heading, now I want to start reading from column 2 to end i.e. 101th column. I am trying with this code :

```
data = np.loadtxt('structure-safety.inp', usecols = [2, 101])
or 
data = pd.read_fwf('structure-safety.inp', usecols = [2,1,101])
```

I also tried with usecols = [2, :], [2:101] or used () instead of [] but in vain, can anyone help me here with this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
data = pd.read_fwf('structure-safety.inp', usecols=list(range(2,102))
```

Keep in mind that the columns are numbered from 0.  So column `2` is actually the third column.

Or you can drop a column:

```
data = pd.read_fwf('structure-safety.inp')
data = data.drop(df.columns[0:2], axis=1)
```

Comment: You may be better off just dropping a column then.  See the edit.